# The augmentation ideal of a commutative group ring $R\left< \sigma \right>$ is generated by $\sigma-1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and $G=<\sigma>$ is a cyclic group.

> Prove that the augmentation ideal in the group ring $RG$ is generated by $\sigma-1$.

**My attempt:**

Since $R$ is commutative, we know ideal generated by $\sigma-1$ is $\{r(\sigma-1):r\in R\}$. And note that any element in Augmentation ideal can be represented by $$ 
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}r_i\sigma^i $$

where $r_i\in R$ and the order of $\sigma$ is $n$. So I want to show that

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}r_i\sigma^i =r(\sigma-1)  $$ for some $r\in R$. But I cannot proceed anymore than this because of powers of $\sigma$. Am I in wrong direction?  I will be happy with any help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The augmentation ideal is generated as an $R$-module by the elements
$\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}\si^k-1$. When $k\ge1$, $\si^k-1=(\si-1)
(\si^{k-1}+\cdots+\si+1)$ lies in $\left<\si-1\right>$. When $k=0$,
$\si^k-1=0$. When $k<0$, $\si^k-1=-\si^k(\si^{|k|}-1)$ which is also
in $\left<\si-1\right>$, since $\si^{|k|}-1$ is.

Comment: Thank you!  I think it suffices to verify for $k\in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Am I right?

Comment: If it's a finite cyclic group, then yes.... @LeB

Comment: Is there any group ring with infinite group?

Comment: Indeed, there s no restriction on the group. @LeB